# Subversion reported an error; Unable to connect to a repository at

Tags: svn

Unable to connect to a repository at ... The HTTP method 'OPTIONS' is not available on /myrepo.

What to do? I'm usuing a pretty vanilla Apache WEB DAV:

```
<Location /myrepo>
DAV svn
SVNPath /var/myrepo
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SVN Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/svn-auth-file
Require valid-user
SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

Comment: Any mention of `OPTIONS` anywhere in your Apache config or `.htaccess` files? Maybe it's disabled? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/disabling-options-method-apache-24-http-server

Comment: No, I have not found anything.

Comment: It's a vanilla Rocky Linux 8 install I'm trying to get working. Had experience before, but this error stopped my efforts for now